# Issue with urllib.request.urlopen in Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, python-3.5, django-1.9

I'm making a website using Django 1.9.7 and Python 3.5. As one feature of the site, I'd like to let a user save a picture to a page by adding a URL to a form and clicking "Save". Before adding the picture where it'll ultimately go, though, I want to notify the user if the link he put in is invalid. So hitting "Save" triggers this view, via AJAX, which just informs the client about whether the URL will ultimately be acceptable.

Unfortunately, while this method does successfully reject everything it should (i.e. invalid URLs and URLs that don't point to pictures), it also rejects maybe half of what it shouldn't (valid URLs that do indeed point to pictures). For example, https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2326994241/dry2n3uwbuscxokvi13t_400x400.jpeg saves fine, but http://aei.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/img-andrewbiggs300x225_151146990889.jpg doesn't. I'm not sure what the difference is.

What I do know, from print statements, is that when it breaks, it seems to break on the line

```
pic = urllib.request.open(picurl)
```

Any thoughts? Here's the full view. Thanks.

```
from django.core.files import File
from io import BytesIO
from django.shortcuts import render
import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request

def pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            picurl = urllib.parse.unquote(form.cleaned_data['picurl'])
            try:
                pic = urllib.request.urlopen(picurl)
                if picurl.endswith('.jpg') or picurl.endswith('.jpeg') or picurl.endswith('.tif') or picurl.endswith('.tiff') or picurl.endswith('.gif') or picurl.endswith('.png') or picurl.endswith('.pdf'):
                    io = BytesIO(pic.read())
                    e = PicTest.objects.create(
                        title="Placeholder",
                    )
                    e.pic.save(
                        os.path.basename(picurl),
                        File(io)
                    )
                    e.save()
                    e.delete()
                    return render(request, 'topics/validpic.html', {'valid':"1"})
            except:
                return render(request, 'topics/validpic.html', {'valid':"0"})
        else:
            return render(request, 'topics/validpic.html', {'valid':"-1"})
```

Comment: I'd say it depends on the remote server wether or not they like your request. Many servers filter on headers. Perhaps you didn't include a referrer, or the right Accept header or User-Agent, or a combination of all 3. Or it was a different header the server didn't like. Servers are like that.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it!